# Vuforia Object Recognition Unity Sample

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, object-recognition, video-tracking

I am trying to implement the Vuforia Object Recognition Unity Sample.

[Vuforia Unity Sample](https://developer.vuforia.com/library//articles/Training/Vuforia-Object-Recognition-Unity-Sample-Guide)

I am using unity 5.3.5f1 and the provided Vuforia extensions. I try to implement the application on a Nexus 7 (Android Version 4.4.3). Building process went fine and the app works, but no tracking is perceptible.

I used the vuforia scanner to scan an object and generate the needed .od file. I don't see any hints that the tracking is working and i don't know what mistake I make. I did not do any modifications on the code of the sample, I just followed the guide and integrated my targets.

Comment: did you get all or mostly green for the scanning process? (and did it work in the scanner app test mode)

Comment: Yes the scanning process went perfect. Test mode tracking was good.

Comment: Have you set the load data set and [x] active and selected object target from the dropdown? (as shown on that tutorial page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. The issue was not part of the actual application. Ich changed place from the scanning process to the test of the application. Lighting conditions and even the surface were the same. I went back to the place where i did the scan to make a test, finally it worked. Vuforia seems not to be very robust due to loghting conditions no matter how small they are.